# A question on a series of sine — as a Fourier coefficient for the wave-equation

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, fourier-series, wave-equation

I have the given series

$$ s_n = \frac{\sin(n\pi)}{n}, \qquad n=0,1,2,3,\dots $$

Now, as a plot, $n$ can be anything, so it would be a plot as [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28sin%28n%20%CF%80%29%29%2Fn). But since the preconditions are that $n$ must be an integer, why is this not $0$, since $\sin n\pi=0$ when $n$ is an integer?

I ask because the following is given on a solution for a PDE:

$$ \cos(x)=u(x,0) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n\cos(nx) \longrightarrow a_n=\begin{cases}1, & n=1\\ 0, & \text{else} \end{cases} $$

That is, the coefficient for a PDE is found by forming the Fourier integral:

$$ \cos(x)=\frac{a_n}{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \cos n x \, {\rm d} x $$

But to me, that integral is simply $0$. So how can it be $1$, for $n = 1$?

Comment: $s_0$ is not defined and $s_n=0$ for $n=1,2,...$.

Comment: It is, in my experience, sometimes customary to associate terms with their limiting value in this scenario. That is,

$$a_0 \ne \frac{\sin(0\pi)}{0} \text{ but rather } a_0 = \lim_{\eta \to 0} \frac{\sin(\eta \pi)}{\eta}$$

reminiscient of a special limit from calculus. Sometimes you might pull out the corresponding term from the sum separately, and then have the remainder index on $n \in \{1,2,3,\cdots\}$. 

Not entirely sure how to answer your other question, but I'm also quite tired. I'll leave that to someone else.

Comment: It's also somewhat like why we write polynomials as $\sum_{n=0}^N a_n x^n$ even though this allows for a potential $0^0$ term, for instance: assuming $0^0=1$ in that very narrow case allows for a compactifying of notation.

Comment: $\cos(x)=\frac{a_n}{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \cos nx dx$ is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficient $a_n$ of the Fourier series of $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\cos (nx)$ is given by

$$a_n=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi\cos (nx)f(x)dx$$

In your case, $f(x)=\cos(x)$ so

$$a_n=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi\cos (nx)\cos(x)dx$$
$$=\begin{cases}
1, & n=1\\
0, & n\ne 1\end{cases}$$

Comment: I checked this integral, and it turns out not to give that answer . Please check. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7B%5Cpi%7D%5Cint_0%5E%5Cpi%5Ccos+%28nx%29%5Ccos%28x%29dx

Comment: The integral is correct. The expression Wolfram Alpha has given has a removable singularity at $n=1$ giving the limit of the integral $1$.

Comment: For $n\ne 1$ the expression on Wolfram alpha is zero, as the part $\sin(n\pi)=0$ when $n$ is an integer.

Comment: @Luthier415Hz If it has answered your question you can accept my answer by the way :)

Comment: This doesn't follow usual PDE solving. Wolfram is saying that the solution is 0 for $n=0,2,3,.., n\ne 1$. and you and the exercise solution are saying that the solution is 0 for n=1,2,3,.., which is true, but it is not $1$ for $n=1$.

Comment: The integral does make sense for $n=1$. Try $\int_0^\pi \cos^2 x dx$ in Wolfram alpha, i.e. the integral when $n=1$.

Comment: I see your point! Thanks